# Is there an extension to manage Keycloak users?

Tags: extension

Is there an extension to manage Keycloak users?
https://www.keycloak.org/

We are using CiviCRM together with drupal 7.

Answer (score 3):

daveawe12323, identity and access are managed at the Drupal level and there is connection between the Drupal "user" and the CiviCRM "contact". It looks like the only Keycloak Drupal module is for Drupal 8 but there is documentation on using Keycloak as OAUTH or OpenID.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is, to do the Keycloak-Usermanagement via a CiviCRM extension. In this case i would be also interested in a hint or an idea how to manage this.

The kc-usermanagement out of the box is not really satisfying - however kc has a good api

greets

Comment: yes this is what i mean. I solved it in this way: Create a cron job which update all keycloak users. I use the civicrm API and the Keycloak API.